# Configuring nginx to allow HTTPS traffic on a custom port

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, nat

I am having a doubt on configuring nginx to forward HTTPS traffic received on a custom port to the same custom port number of the destination url. My case is given below.

1. I have a VPC in AWS. I'm running nginx on the NAT (a Bastion server in my case) instance which receives HTTPS traffic.
2. My app-instance within the VPC is the destination for the requests forwarded by nginx. It has two custom sub-domains, one for one-way SSL authentication and the other for two-way SSL authentication.
3. I am serving the URI having two-way authentication on a custom port , rather than 443. The URIs having services running on port 443 use a one-way SSL authentication (server authentication).
4. In my nginx configuration file, I listen on this custom port to get the HTTPS requests redirected to the same custom port on the app-instance, after the SSL handshake is done. But I observed that after the handshake phase, it was being redirected to port 443, by default, of the app-instance.
5. The HTTPS packets are being sent using a HTTPBuilder object that is available in Java/Groovy, after setting up a HTTPS scheme.

A sample nginx configuration which I'm using is given here:

```
server {
 listen 8000;
 server_name myserver.com;
 ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /path/to/server/cert;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/server/key;
    ssl_client_certificate /path/to/client/cert;
    ssl_verify_client on;
 #https requests to this URI gets redirected to port 443 by default
 location /customUri1 {
        # switch off logging
        access_log off;
        proxy_pass http://app-instance-ip:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  }
}
server {
 listen 443;
 server_name myserver.com;
 ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /path/to/server/cert;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/server/key;
 location /customUri2 {
        # switch off logging
        access_log off;
        proxy_pass http://app-instance-ip:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;      
  }
}
```

Is there any nginx configuration mechanism which might allow me to send the HTTPS requests to the custom port on the app-instance? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was with the way I was posting the HTTPS packets to the server. In my Groovy code, the HTTPBuilder's uri.port field was set to 443 rather than 8000. After replacing it with 8000, my client is able to post to the server.

Comment: How did you managed to use client certificates with your groovy code?